# limiting output through templates when using json and underscore

Tags: javascript, json, templates, underscore.js

i have a json file which i am using to fill data in my template.

```
[
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"},
     { id:1 ,imgsrc:"images/wedding.jpg" ,name:"wedding"}


]
```

i am currently using _.each function to populate my template, but this results in all my data getting loaded to my screen is there a way to limit the output and then show the remaining data in counts of 4 when some button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the `slice` method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
var abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
var itemsPerPage = 2;
var page3ItemsBegin = itemsPerPage * 2;

console.log(abc.slice(page3ItemsBegin, page3ItemsBegin + itemsPerPage));
```

Working example [here](https://jsbin.com/nubujodixu/1/edit?js,console)